# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, ubuntu, servidor

**MYSQL** comenzó a marcarme error y no puedo acceder por consola ni phpmyadmin, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mi sistema lo accede normal pero yo no, y necesito actualizar la base de datos.

> la contraseña es correcta y no fué modificada

o alguna manera de modificar, ya que ni para eso puedo acceder

Comment: ¿Cómo estás entrando a `phpmyadmin`? ¿No estarás apuntando a otra base de datos o algo así?

Comment: Cuidado, porque -p contraseña no es correcto, es -pcontraseña todo junto, sin el espacio.

Comment: ¿Cómo se apunta a otra base de datos? `192.168.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin/`

Comment: y al ponelo junto, me sale lo mismo, pero con algo mas `mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

Comment: Si por ejemplo la dirección IP que indicas en `192.168.xxx.xxx` no es la del servidor donde está la BD a la que quieres conectar, ya estás apuntando a otra BD en otra dirección.